# Bitnami redmine error SVN

Tags: svn, redmine, bitnami

I'm installing the Bitnami Redmine stack (redmine + subversion). Firstly I install configure and test it locally (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). And everything is OK.

I install Bitnami stack on server (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) and configure SVN.
I commit files into SVN and connect project into Redmine with SVN repository, but when I try see it Rredmine displays 404 error. In the Redmine log file I see the following errors:

```
Started GET "/redmine/projects/web-user-panel/repository" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-24 11:34:20 +0300
Processing by RepositoriesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"web-user-panel"}
  Current user: user (id=13)
Error parsing svn output: #<REXML::ParseException: No close tag for /lists/list>
/var/www/html/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:28:in `parse'
/var/www/html/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/document.rb:245:in `build'
/var/www/html/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rexml/document.rb:43:in `initialize'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/xml_mini/rexml.rb:30:in `new'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/xml_mini/rexml.rb:30:in `parse'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:80:in `parse'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:313:in `parse_xml'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/subversion_adapter.rb:106:in `block in entries'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:258:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:258:in `block in shellout'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:255:in `popen'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:255:in `shellout'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:212:in `shellout'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/lib/redmine/scm/adapters/subversion_adapter.rb:100:in `entries'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/repository.rb:198:in `scm_entries'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/models/repository.rb:203:in `entries'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/controllers/repositories_controller.rb:116:in `show'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:491:in `_run__2883861927089110970__process_action__2542827355008294621__callbacks'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-openid-1.3.1/lib/rack/openid.rb:98:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.17/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1805290955544829105__call__1486932417638469082__callbacks'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:64:in `block in call'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `each'
/var/www/html/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:49:in `call'
/var/www/html/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
/var/www/html/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/var/www/html/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
/var/www/html/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.40/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
...
No close tag for /lists/list
Line: 4
Position: 93
Last 80 unconsumed characters:

Output was:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lists>
<list
   path="svn://127.0.0.1/voxysuser">

  Rendered common/error.html.erb within layouts/base (0.1ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 69.1ms (Views: 15.1ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

How can I resolve this problem? I googled it, but similar problem fixed should be fixed 3 years ago.

I'm installing the latest Bitnami Redmine 2.5.1-1 stack.

**UPDATE** Well, I found next way. If I use the http protocol it works fine, but I should remove access for svn by web. That's why I create virtual host on localhost and get info from svn use 127.0.0.1 IP.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8000>
<Location /repo>                                  
    DAV svn                                                                         
    SVNPath "PATH_TO_MY_REPOSITORY"                                         
</Location>
```

And this it work good.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a permissions problem with the SVN user, see here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Error_parsing_svn_output

> If you find this error in production.log there's probably an error
>   when the redmine user runs the svn command:
>
> Error parsing svn output: #
>
> (Redmine still tries to parse the output of the svn command as XML,
>   but errors aren't formatted as XML, thus the parse error.)
>
> To troubleshoot try running the command as the redmine user to see
>   what the error is, for example:
>
> sudo -u www-data svn list --xml
>   'https://svn.server.address/reponame'@HEAD
>
> (You may have to add "www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" to
>   /etc/sudoers)